# Monad transformers with identity monad

Tags: haskell

What's the point in using a Monad transformer with the Identity monad rather than just using the "standard" version of the transformer?

Is it more flexible?

Comment: What do you mean by "standard" version?

Comment: What do you mean, 'the "standard" version of the transformer'? Normally, it _is_ the standard version of the transformer that's applied to the identity monad.

Comment: I mean `StateT s Identity a` vs `State s a` Both are the same functionally, right?

Comment: I believe some of the standard monads actually **are** defined as an alias for the transformer version applied to `Indentity`. Doing so avoids the code duplication of implementing the monad twice.

Comment: Isn’t there a performance penalty then? Or can GHC optimize the Identity monad completely away?

Comment: There is no performance penalty for `newtype` wrapping and unwrapping, so, usually not.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Back in `mtl` 1.0 we had both

```
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a, s) }
```

and

```
newtype StateT s m a = StateT { runStateT :: s -> m (a, s) }
```

However, this meant anybody who had to implement instances for things like `MonadState` wound up duplicating effort.

In `transformers` (and the now defunct `monads-fd` and `monads-tf`) Ross Paterson decided to use the simpler approach of only offering the latter and using `Identity` as the base monad.

This led to reduced implementation effort in maintaining the `mtl` and removed the fact that there were two different ways to implement the `State` monad. It did, however, make the internals of the `mtl` harder to teach, because you need to understand the `transformers` versions right out of the gate and don't get the simplified version as training wheels.

When the old `mtl` was retired and `monads-fd` became `mtl` 2.0, using the existing `transformers` this design decision was carried over.

I personally liked having the separate simple monads for pedagogical purposes at least, but there were far more people on the other side of the debate.

Comment: I totally agree about teaching purposes.  Maybe we should set up a `monads-teach` package which contains the original simpler versions.

Answer (score 11):

From the Documentation: *Computationally, there is no reason to use the Identity monad instead of the much simpler act of simply applying functions to their arguments. The purpose of the Identity monad is its fundamental role in the theory of monad transformers. Any monad transformer applied to the Identity monad yields a non-transformer version of that monad.*

As i understand it, getting the non-transformer version of a monad from a monad transformer by applying the identity monad is exactly the thing that the identity monad is there for. There is no advantage over just using the non-transformer monad, yet sometimes you have to use a monad transformer, e.g. when a function you want to use requires it.