# Deriving a base monad using a monad transformer and the identity monad

Tags: haskell, monads

I read (for example [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/All_About_Monads#The_Identity_monad) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946633/monad-transformers-with-identity-monad)) that all of the base monads 
(`Mabye`, `Error`, ...) are derived from their corresponding monad transformers 
(`MaybeT`, `ErrorT`, ...) using the identity monad `Identity`. An example would be:

```
type Maybe a = MaybeT Identity a
```

But that of course doesn't result in a constructor for `Maybe a`.
And in the [sources](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.0.0/docs/src/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html) `MaybeT` is defined as `newtype MaybeT m a = MaybeT (m (Maybe a))`.

Am I missing something important? 
How could one derive a base monad using the corresponding monad transformer and the identitiy monad resulting in a concrete
constructor that can be matched against?

Comment: `Maybe` is defined in `base`, monad transformers generally come from a library like `transformers` or `mtl`.  The `Error` monad also comes from a library, along with `State`, `Reader`, and `Writer`.  In this case, `Maybe` and `MaybeT` are the odd ones out.

Comment: `MaybeT Identity a` is equivalent to `Maybe a` -- it reduces to a newtype `MaybeT` around `Identity (Maybe a)` -- but it's not literally the same thing, partially because `Maybe` is treated as a data structure first and a monad second.

Comment: "An example would be `type Maybe a = MaybeT Identity a`." [No](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/src/Data-Maybe.html#Maybe), but a correct example would be [`type State s = StateT s Identity`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/src/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#State).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different approaches are being used here.

Sometimes, the base monad `Foo` is defined in terms of its transformer as `FooT Identity`. For example, [`State`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/src/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#State) from transformer package, as Daniel Wagner points out.

Other times, the base monad `Foo` is defined independently. In these cases, it usually happens that `Foo` and `FooT Indentity` are distinct types, which however are *isomorphic*. This means that you can convert between both types without losing any information.

I guess that since `Maybe` is defined in the Haskell report as a `Prelude` type, we can not easily redefine it as the isomorphic `MaybeT Identity`. Indeed, since it's common to destruct/eliminate values in `Maybe a` by pattern matching against `Nothing` and `Just _`, we can't use another definition. If we *had* user-definable patterns we could use `pattern Just x = Module.Just (Identity x)`, but we have not these (for now).

Instead, other monads such as `State` are not in the `Prelude`, nor in the Haskell report. They are also not typically destructed via pattern matching by whomever is importing `Control.Monad.State`. In such cases, it felt less harmful to move to the `StateT Identity` variant.

Comment: Are you confusing `Maybe` with `Either` here? `Maybe` has neither `Left` nor `Right` constructors. Losing pattern matching on maybe probably wouldn't be a huge loss anyway, since utility functions like `maybe` and `fromMaybe` are already part of base.

Comment: I sometimes *wish* `StateT` were abstract. Some people are foolish enough to pattern match on it, and send everyone else racing around looking up which component of the result tuple is which.

Answer (score 2):

The `Maybe` monad is not defined as `MaybeT Identity a` for backwards compatibility, since `Maybe` was part of GHC long before `MaybeT`.

You are correct that using a monad transformer with `Identity` would not result in a type constructor that can be matched on. Fortunately, I've never had to pattern match on monad constructors when using the monad transformer paradigm. Instead, you can use `do` notation and monad operations (`liftM`, `runReaderT`, etc).